# How do I use the cv2.imread function to read multiple images to display bounding boxes over them without having to include the path

Tags: python

How do I use the cv2.imread function to read multiple images to display bounding boxes over them without having to include the path?

```
images = [
("images/audrey.jpg", np.array([
(12, 84, 140, 212),
(24, 84, 152, 212),
(36, 84, 164, 212),
(12, 96, 140, 224),
(24, 96, 152, 224),
(24, 108, 152, 236)])),
("images/bksomels.jpg", np.array([
(114, 60, 178, 124),
(120, 60, 184, 124),
(114, 66, 178, 130)])),
("images/gpripe.jpg", np.array([
(12, 30, 76, 94),
(12, 36, 76, 100),
(72, 36, 200, 164),
(84, 48, 212, 176)]))]
```

*looping over the images*

```
for (imagePath, boundingBoxes) in images:
    # load the image and clone it
    print ("[x] %d initial bounding boxes" % (len(boundingBoxes)))
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    orig = image.copy()
```

Comment: Don't see any boundingbox related info in your question. Kindly add that.

Comment: can you share some content of images array so that its easy to answer your question?

Comment: This is the image array from the code. I apologize for leaving it out, I only just started coding with python.